# Fitted Values in UCM

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

How can we view the fitted values for the UCM function in R? I have tried below code to make the model.

```
model_h_fcast <- ucm(hourly_2~0, data = hourly_2, irregular =  TRUE, 
                     level =  TRUE, slope = FALSE).
```

Then I tried to `fitted.values(model_h_forecast)` OR `fitted(model_h_forecast)` however its giving out `NULL`.

Comment: Hello, any one is listning! I guess the RUCM package is still now perfect.

Comment: Did you try predict function/

Comment: @KRC predict function is for predicting future values. I want to see what are the fitted values for the training data.

Answer (score 1):

Try fitted.values(model_h_fcast$model)